# Getting complete description of video using YouTube API v3

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using YT API to fetch video description. I can use older API to fetch complete description of video using api call like this: [API CALL](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=json&callback=youtubeFeedCallback&q=football)
But using the newer API call truncates the description after 160 characters. example: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=API_KEY_HERE&part=snippet&fields=items(snippet(title,description,categoryId))

Any idea about how I can get full description of a video from googleapis and not gdata.youtube(it is truncated).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've confused things a bit with the request URLs you posted, as they are retrieving different types of data. Basically, with a *search* request (whether the search feed in the old V2 API that you've posted, or the search endpoint in the new V3 API which you didn't post an example of) will always return truncated descriptions. A *videos* request (which you have an example of for V3 but not for V2) will return the full video description. This is true for v2 or v3.

Comment: He already has the full description - he wants the html not the plain text.